# Does the system kill a backgrounded/in-memory app during the update process on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

If a third party app is backgrounded on iOS (still in memory) and the user updates the app from the App Store, will the app be terminated before or during the installation process? Is there any way for a backgrounded app to remain in memory after being upgraded? Will the app always receive the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` callback when opened after an update?

(My assumption is that the app is killed and completely removed from memory, given that the app's executable code has likely changed during the update.)

Comment: I am asking from the developer's perspective. Yes, the app will be in the multitasking bar, but will it be guaranteed to have been killed and removed from memory? Will the app always receive the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` callback when opened after an update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be killed. Whether it is terminated before, during or after the update is irrelevant - you should have saved state when the received the [applicationDidEnterBackground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a). There is **no** way that an app could continue executing once it's underlying code has changed - structures may have changed, you could have rewritten the threading model so that it does everything completely differently.

You will have to save state and attempt to restore it if it is compatible; otherwise you should start from scratch. You should save the state in the [applicationDidEnterBackground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a) call - you will probably not get an opportunity in the [applicationWillTerminate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate%3a) call, as it will probably not be called.

Comment: Yep, I understand everything around state restoration. Was more curious about the implications to the next app startup -- basically, this means after an update, the app will be launched from scratch instead of resumed, meaning a longer startup time, and any singletons or similar objects that persist for the lifetime of the app will be reinstantiated in memory. It also means the launch image will always display after an update as opposed to a screenshot of the UI saved on last background.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: Yes, your application will be terminated at some point during the upgrade. There really isn't a way of keeping the application running while changing the underlying code.